# UIWebView autorotation weird behavior

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, autorotate

I managed to show a UIWebView that shows content from the internet.
But apparently it does not rotate as it should:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VV0BmNkSrvU

I'm using this code:

```
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!window) {
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
}
_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
_webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:URL];    NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
//Unity's UIView
UIView* subView = [window.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
[url release];
[subView addSubview:_webView];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this code has not been placed inside a UIViewController. Autorotation works correctly only inside a UIViewController. If you want to manage it outside a UIViewController you must observe all orientation change notifications and then transform your view accordingly.

Comment: However this is only present on my iPod Touch 2nd gen (v4.2.1) The same code runs fine on the iPhone 4 (v4.2.1)